# Adding special column names to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data frame (lets say df). I have factor f.
I would like to insert this factor to p[1], p[2]..., p[k]
Where k is integer positive number. So each of them will become new column in dataframe df.  The column names in the dataframe will be kept as p[1], p[2]..., p[k].

How can I insert f into p[1]..p[k] by loop? And how can I add them all each as a new column to df (the dataframe)? It is important to keep their number in each new column.
Here is an example for df:

```
> df
  var1 var2 var3
1   ac   bc   bc
2   bc   bc   cc
3   dc   ec   dc
4   gc   gc   gc
```

I have a factor:

```
> f
[1] setosa     setosa     setosa   versicolor
Levels: setosa versicolor
```

If k =2 I would like to have df as:

```
> df
  var1 var2 var3  p[1]        p[2]
1   ac   bc   bc  setosa     setosa
2   bc   bc   cc  setosa     setosa
3   dc   ec   dc  setosa     setosa
4   gc   gc   gc  versicolor versicolor
```

Comment: This reads like an [xy-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It's also difficult to understand what exactly you want to do. Please show exactly what you have, what you want, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
for (i in 1:2) df[[sprintf("p[%i]", i)]] <- f
#  var1 var2 var3       p[1]       p[2]
#1   ac   bc   bc     setosa     setosa
#2   bc   bc   cc     setosa     setosa
#3   dc   ec   dc     setosa     setosa
#4   gc   gc   gc versicolor versicolor
```

Of course, I can't think of any good reason why you should need this. There is surely a better approach to you actual problem.

It's always a bad idea to use names that are not syntactical valid.

Comment: Maybe just `k <- 2 ; df[sprintf("p[%i]", 1:k)] <- f` without a loop? Though strange question indeed...

Comment: Roland is right, this will get you into trouble. For example, calling `df$p[1]` will return `NULL` and not the vector you're after.

Comment: Thank you all. My purpose is before entering f into the data frame to replicate it into p[1],...,p[k] factors. So I'll be able to use p[1] and p[2] as well as df$p[1] and df$p[2] etc...

Comment: Avi the naming convention you chose will create extra work for you down the line. You have to use backticks to access the contents of the variable (`df$'p[1]'`). It will become even messier if you need a single element of the column (`df$'p[1]'[1]`)

Comment: Thank you this works. The only missing part is to insert f into p[1], p[2] before inserting it into df. What do I have to add?

Comment: @Avi I simply don't understand you. You are doing strange things for unknown reasons. Since you don't seem to be experienced with R, you should heed the advice that you shouldn't do this.